# How to sync every file under /srv/salt from Salt Master to Salt Syndic

Tags: linux, salt-stack

Ran across a situation where I needed to keep the files sync'd from my Salt Master to my Syndic.  I searched online but couldn't really find any real solution other than the usual, "use a shared filesystem, rsync them over, etc).

Those solutions may be an option for others but for my environment, that would not work and needed a solution within Salt to do this.

After searching and testing, I modified the closest solution I was able to find and came up with the following that keeps /srv/salt sync'd on the Syndic to what's on the Master:

```
{% for file in salt['cp.list_master']() %}
/srv/salt/{{ file }}:
  file.managed:
    - name: /srv/salt/{{ file }}
    - source: salt://{{ file }}
    - user: salt
    - group: salt
    - mode: 640
    - makedirs: True
{% endfor %}
```

Hope this helps others!

Comment: Any reason you're using 640 for the mode? You don't have secrets in the fileserver do you?

Comment: as far as 640, there's no reason for us to open it up to world readable.

Answer (score 0):

If you can set up the credentials, an rsync state will probably have better performance:

```yaml
/srv/salt:
  rsync.synchronized:
    - source: salt:/srv/salt
    - delete: true
    - force: true
```

You might also consider a different [fileserver backend](https://docs.saltproject.io/en/latest/py-modindex.html#cap-f) that can be more easily shared.

---

Unfortunately, this doesn't work. It looks like a bug in the `source` parser.

```yaml
/srv/salt:
  file.recurse:
    - source: salt://
    - clean: true
    - keep_symlinks: true
```

Comment: Unfortunately, with `file.recurse` example you show, I receive the following:

`Invalid source 'salt:' (must be a salt:// URI)`

this is the reason I went with the solution I posted.

Comment: @cspilman What if you quote it: `- source: 'salt://'`?

Comment: Unfortunately, similar error message:

`Invalid source 'salt:' (must be a salt:// URI)`

Comment: I encountered similar errors during my initial testing which led me to the solution I originally posted to hopefully help others if they find themselves in a similar situation.  

would be nice if I could get the code cleaned up more but for me, I'm good with the solution I came up with.

again, hope it helps others.

Comment: Your version doesn't remove anything that is removed, is the main problem

Comment: agreed, but until I have a better solution that allows that ability, I will use what I originally posted.   unfortunately, this was the only solution that works for me.

Comment: You could write a bit more code to have all the top-level directories done with `file.recurse` and the `top.sls`  with `file.managed`.